# Is this ring a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Stuck on this one - never done anything with $x^3$ before, and I tried to factorizing but that didn't go well.

Decide whether the following statement is true or false. Explain the
answer.
The ring $$ \mathbb Q[x]/\langle x^3 - 231x^2 +  363x  - 1001\rangle$$   is a field

Comment: A monic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $3$ with integral coefficients is irreducible if and only if it has no integral root. So all you need to do is check the divisors of $1001$ to be roots of your polynomial...

Comment: ... or use a certain irreducibility criterion.

Comment: Hint: 231, 363 and 1001 are all divisible by 11 (and 1001 not by 121)

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Take $p = 11$ and use [Eisenstein's Criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein's_criterion) to conclude that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$. And use if a $f$ is irreducible then $\langle f\rangle$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb Q[x]$.

Answer (score 5):

Fact: Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and $I$ an ideal of $R$.  $R/I$ is a field if and only if $I$ is maximal.

The ideal $I=\langle x^3-231x^2+363x-1001\rangle$ is maximal if and only if there does not exist a proper ideal $J$ such that $I\subsetneq J$.

Now, $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a PID, so $I$ is maximal if and only if there does not exist $J=\langle f\rangle$ such that $f$ is not a unit and $I\subsetneq J$.  Since $x^3-231x^2+363x-1001\in I$, the existence of such a $J$ would imply that $f\mid x^3-231x^2+363x-1001$.

Now, using Eisenstein's criterion, you can see that $x^3-231x^2+363x-1001$ is irreducible, so no $f$ exists.

Comment: Without using any software, how would you do suggest doing the arithmetic for Eisenstein's criterion?

Comment: @goblin Take $p = 11$.

Comment: @goblin I would notice that $363$ is divisible by $3$, then $363=3\cdot 121$, which factors nicely.  It is easy to see that $3\nmid 1001$, so you're left with checking Eisenstein's criterion for 11, which just means that you have to divide by 11.

Comment: How do you know that $11$ divides $231$ and $363$ and $1001$. but that $121$ does not divide $1001$? @AaronMaroja

Comment: @goblin Use long division.

Comment: @goblin It took me longer to answer, because I was computing it by hand. The "problem" was $1001$ divided by $121$. But it's easier if you see that $1001 = 11 \dot \ 91 $ and $121 = 11 \dot \  11$ and there is no $11$ factoring $91$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the polynomial $f(x)=x^3-231x^2+363x-1001$ is irreducible (why ? Eisenstein with $p=11$), so that the quotient is a field.